# How to prevent ASP.NET RequiredFieldValidator from doing a postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent my form from doing a postback. I'm in ASP.NET 4.5 and C# (web app project, not website). I've done this effectively in several versions of ASP.NET, but I can't figure out how to prevent a postback on a simple required field validation. The validation is working once the form refreshes. Here's my code:

```
<label for="MainContent_txtName" class="required">Name</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required field" ControlToValidate="txtName" EnableClientScript="true" ValidationGroup="contact" />

<label for="MainContent_txtEmail" class="required">Email Address</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<label for="MainContent_txtPhone">Phone Number</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<label for="MainContent_txtComment" class="required">Question or Comment</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="contact"  />
```

I've tried without the ValidationGroup, CausesValidation, and EnableClientScript (with several variations of each). Also, there is a form that wraps this in the masterpage. I'm just trying to simply validate that a field is not empty on the client side before submitting the form. Any help is appreciated. I figure I'm blatantly missing something simple.

Comment: Could you just handle the form submit event client side and return false if the validation fails?

Comment: wrap the code for the button in an update panel that could be a good start button click will always trigger a postback if I am following your question correctly also look at __DoPostBack() and use JavaScript if you like if fails then return else do something

Comment: What does "The validation is working once the form refreshes." mean exactly?

Comment: I haven't done WebForms for a while but pre-validation in JavaScript was one of the key points of the validators. So how do you verify the behavior, what Browser(-version), is JavaScript enabled at all?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorry for the confusion. When the page finishes the postback = once the form refreshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just decided to not try and accomplish anything on the client side and validate on the server side using Page.IsValid and .IsValid. In addition, I'm using ScriptManager/UpdatePanel to avoid page refresh. Much cleaner and a lot more control of the UI when validations fail. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property EnableClientScript to True

`<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="TextBoxRequiredValidator" 
        controltovalidate="NumberTextBox"
        enableclientscript="True"
        display="Dynamic" 
        errormessage="Please enter a value."
        text="*"
        runat="server"/>`

Comment: By default it should be true if im not mistaking

Comment: I looked in the DOM inspector and it is saying JQuery 1.7.1 can't be found. So I dropped JQuery in the Scripts path and the error went away, but it still is doing a postback each time. Super frustrating.